# Best way to constantly request http data?

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2, urllib3

Which is the best way to request constant data from a server in Python? I've tried with Urllib3 but for some reason after a while the python script stops. And I am also trying urllib2 (see below the code), but I notice there's a huge delay sometimes (that did not happen as frequently with urllib3) and the response is not every 0.5 seconds (sometimes it's every 6 seconds). What can I do to solve this?

```
import socket
import urllib2
import time

# timeout in seconds
timeout = 10
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

while True:
    try:
        # this call to urllib2.urlopen now uses the default timeout
        # we have set in the socket module
        req = urllib2.Request('https://www.okcoin.com/api/v1/future_ticker.do?symbol=btc_usd&contract_type=this_week')
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        r = response.read()

        req2 = urllib2.Request('http://market.bitvc.com/futures/ticker_btc_week.js')
        response2 = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
        r2 = response2.read()
    except:
        continue

    print r + str(time.time())
    print r2 + str(time.time())
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: make the internet go faster? (you are likely running into request rate limiting by the API you are requesting that fails for 6 seconds if you do too many requests)

Comment: "Request constant data"? If you wanted a continual stream, you'd want to connect to a service that uses an appropriately extended streaming protocol (SSE, server-sent events, is a common approach -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events), rather than giving you a single HTTP document -- which is to say, doing this right would mean having the *server* written to support it explicitly; it's not something you can do purely on the client side. There are numerous other long-polling approaches available as well, but they all require server support.

Comment: ...you may also see a feed of the kind you would want to continually stream updates described under several other names; see ie. the numerous names for techniques falling under the category in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: ...beyond that, the way to write a client in Python depends on which variant of this set of techniques the service you end up using supports; for SSE, for instance, you might end up with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sseclient/0.0.8

Comment: I think the answer is more likely related to the http session....

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I needed to keep an open http session. That way I get the data more continuously. What's the best way of doing this? I did "http = requests.Session()" and using requests now.